Tikz figures in External Files
I have a tikz figure in an external file which has animations (overlays) as shown below:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node<1> at (0,0) {\Huge \textbf{1}};
    \node<2> at (0,0) {\Huge \textbf{2}};
    \node<3> at (0,0) {\Huge \textbf{3}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

And I'm including this figure in my main beamer document:
\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics{images/tikz/exp2.pdf}
\end{frame}

Overlays, <1> etc, work in the same beamer file. But overlays do not work when in external files. Is there any way to have the tikz figures in an external file and also it's overlays working properly ?

You can use the standalone beamer option in combination with the standaloneframe environment to allow using overlays in the standalone class:
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node<1> at (0,0) {\Huge \textbf{1}};
    \node<2> at (0,0) {\Huge \textbf{2}};
    \node<3> at (0,0) {\Huge \textbf{3}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}



This will be included in the main beamer doc as a complete slide right? I can't embed this as a picture within my main slide ?

It is up to you. You can include this as picture or as complete page (but if you use it as complete page, any frame decorations like navigations symbols, head- and footline will be missing)

Sorry I am a beginner here. How do I include it as a picture? the "\include{pic.tex}" command causes errors as some commands in the tikz file (like documentclass) must be in the preamble and can't be included in the middle of a document.

@fakhir To include it as picture, compile the standalone document first and then use the \includegraphics{...} as you've shown in your question. For other pages than the first, use  \includegraphics[page=2]{...} etc.
